# Gift App from inside the app with iOS6 gifting

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store, itunes-store

Is there a new direct link to the iOS6 gifting page?  The following URL links to the iOS5 gifting page when launched from an iOS device:

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard?gift=1&salableAdamId=343200656&productType=C&pricingParameter=STDQ

The gifting page in iOS6 has changed and now let's you select a date for the gift.  This option doesn't appear when visiting the link above.  Is there a new URL that will open the iOS6 gifting page?